# How to bring ajax search onkeyup with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

*My Script to call ajax*

```
<script language="javascript">
function search_func(value)
{
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "sample.php",
       data: {'search_keyword' : value},
       dataType: "text",
       success: function(msg){
                   //Receiving the result of search here
       }
    });
}
</script>
```

*HTML*

```
   <input type="text" name="sample_search" id="sample_search" onkeyup="search_func(this.value);">
```

***Question:*** while onkeyup I am using ajax to fetch the result. Once ajax result delay increases problem occurs for me.

**For Example**
While typing `t` keyword I receive ajax result and while typing `te` I receive ajax result
when ajax time delay between two keyup sometime makes a serious issue.

When I type `te` fastly. ajax search for `t` keyword come late, when compare to `te`. I don't know how to handle this type of cases.

**Result** 
While typing `te` keyword fastly due to ajax delays. result for `t` keyword comes.

I believe I had explained up to reader knowledge.

Comment: Couple of pointers. Firstly, language is a deprecated attribute of javascript. In HTML(5) you can leave the attribute off, or use type="text/javascript". Secondly, you are using jQuery so why do you have an inline function call when you can do that with jQuery too? $(function(){ $("#sample_search").keyup(function() {

Comment: Just to bump a suggestion from below up to the top [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default) has a useful autocomplete function built in to it. It took me 15/20 minutes of googling to find the right combination of tutorials to find what I wanted. For those looking to interact with a DB, [this](http://www.htmlblog.us/jquery-autocomplete) is a decent guide.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You should check if the value has changed over time:

```
var searchRequest = null;

$(function () {
    var minlength = 3;

    $("#sample_search").keyup(function () {
        var that = this,
        value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length >= minlength ) {
            if (searchRequest != null) 
                searchRequest.abort();
            searchRequest = $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "sample.php",
                data: {
                    'search_keyword' : value
                },
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(msg){
                    //we need to check if the value is the same
                    if (value==$(that).val()) {
                    //Receiving the result of search here
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

The `searchRequest` variable was added to prevent multiple unnecessary requests to the server.

Comment: Yet this leads to multiple requests to the server. Suppose that I am typing 'test', in this case sample.php is still called four times - one for each alphabet of 'test' leading unwanted server load. Any other alternative to avoid this?

Comment: Could someone please be kind to explain to me how the `$searchRequest`, actually, prevents multiple unnecessary requests? In which scenario could this apply ? Thank you

Answer (score 25):

Keep hold of the `XMLHttpRequest` object that `$.ajax()` returns and then on the next keyup, call .abort().  That should kill the previous ajax request and let you do the new one.

```
var req = null;

function search_func(value)
{
    if (req != null) req.abort();

    req = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "sample.php",
        data: {'search_keyword' : value},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(msg){
                    //Receiving the result of search here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Even if this is not answering the question directly, it has solved another big problem of multiple AJAX requests.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). Saves you from many low-level coding.

Answer (score 0):

First i will suggest that making a ajax call on every keyup is not good (and this why u run in this problem) .

Second if you want to use keyup then show a loading image after input box to show user its still loading (use loading image like you get on adding comment)

Answer (score 0):

Keep hold of the XMLHttpRequest object that $.ajax() returns and then on the next keyup, call .abort(). That should kill the previous ajax request and let you do the new one.

```
var req = null;

function search_func(value)
{
    if (req != null) req.abort();

    req = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "sample.php",
        data: {'search_keyword' : value},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(msg){
                //

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Couple of pointers. Firstly, language is a deprecated attribute of javascript. In HTML(5) you can leave the attribute off, or use type="text/javascript". Secondly, you are using jQuery so why do you have an inline function call when you can do that with jQuery too?

```
$(function(){

   // Document is ready

   $("#sample_search").keyup(function()
   {

       $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "sample.php",
          data: {'search_keyword' : value},
          dataType: "text",
          success: function(msg)
          {
               //Receiving the result of search here
          }
       });

   });

});
```

I would suggest leaving a little delay between the keyup event and calling an ajax function. What you could do is use setTimeout to check that the user has finished typing before then calling your ajax function.